# PHP, SESSION How to show users who are logged in, a hidden Link

Tags: php, variables, session

Once a person has logged-in and a session is created, how do I display a element that only logged-in members can see. What I believed would work was to type in the body of the element I wanted to hide was: if it is set session name and is set session user_id = true display the current element I'm hiding.

```
<?php
   session_start();
?>

   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
   <title> <?php $page_title ?> </title>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>   
    <script src="formValidation.js"></script>

 </head>
   <body>

    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="header">

         <div id="login"> <a href="login.php">Login</a> </div>

         <h1>Films.com</h1>

     <?php  if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && isset($_SESSION['name'])){

              echo "Logged in as " . $_SESSION['name'];
        }

      ?>


    </div>

       <div id="nav">

            <ul>

                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
                <li><a href="film.php">Film</a></li>

                <?php 

                 if (isset($_session['user_id']) and isset($_SESSION['name'])) {

                     echo "<li><a href='review_a_film.php'>Review a film</a></li>";

                   } ?>

                <li><a href="logout.php">logout</a></li>


            </ul>

        </div>
```

Comment: What's your problem? And what does your code have to do with your question title?

Comment: Trying to display a element for the people who are logged in

Comment: Where are you setting the `user_id` and `name` session vars?

Comment: Please also read about Cross side scripting and next tip don't trust $_SESSION array to to safe on an shared webhosting account. PHP doens't check what session id belongs to what site so sessions are prone to session reading or poisoning... you should always set the session save path (never allow that php sessions write to /tmp/ or an common direcory) or use database session handling

Comment: Their created and stored in the login.php.

Comment: If you like you can write me to the skype: `linas.rakauskas`, since you will not get help here, this type of question doesn't really belong in stackoverflow. And I would be able to teach you how to solve problems like these.

Answer (score 1):

The variable $_session['user_id'] is lower case. Where as the the first $_SESSION variable is upper case.

```
 <?php if (isset($_session['user_id']) and isset($_SESSION['name'])) {

                 echo "<li><a href='review_a_film.php'>Review a film</a></li>";

                 } ?>
```